# Return only unique value SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a csv file from a SQL query.
But while writing this query I encounter a problem, I try to retreive all the tableA IDs in the case where valueA = valueB, but in the case where the valueB exists several times in the tableB, I don't want to retreive the tableA ID.

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.id FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.valueA = tableB.valueB
```

Currently my result looks like this : 
tableA.id;tableB.id
------------------------ 
1;100 
2;123 
5;148 
5;256 
7;130

And so for this example, it would be necessary to have no value for ID 5 and to have the following result : 
tableA.id;tableB.id
------------------------ 
1;100 
2;123 
7;130

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer which is easy to read, but can be a bit slow with large tables:

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.id 
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN tableB 
ON tableA.valueA = tableB.valueB
where (select count(1) from tableB b2 where b2.valueB = tableB.valueB) = 1
```

And here's a more complicated version which only queries tableB once.

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.id 
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN (select tableB.*, count(1) over (partition by valueB) as c from tableB) tableB 
ON tableA.valueA = tableB.valueB
 AND tableB.c = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
select * from tableA inner join (
select * from tableB where valueB in (
select valueB  from tableB group by valueB having count(valueB) = 1 ) 
) tableBB
on tableA.valueA = tableBB.valueB
```

Idea is to first filter out the multiple row id from tableB and then join it with tableA.